# How can I continuously loop my Bitcoin price checker?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I've made a bitcoin price checker that sends me alerts to tell me Bitcoins current price. It also lets me know when Bitcoin has moved into a certain price range.

It's working good so far, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to keep my while loop (`run_loop`) running continuously. I want the code to run on a timed interval say every 30 minutes for example. I want it to loop and tell me the price after a set amount of time without me re-running the code manually.

```
import smtplib
import os
import requests
import json
import time

email_user = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')  # set your own environment variables
email_password = os.environ.get('APP_PASS')
phone_number = os.environ.get('USER_PHONE')

target_price = 20000   # set your target prices in USD
target_price_2 = 30000

current_price = 0 # declare current price

def send_email(current_price):

    with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) as smtp:
        smtp.ehlo()
        smtp.starttls()
        smtp.ehlo()

        smtp.login(email_user, email_password)

        subject = 'Bitcoin Alert: '
        body = 'Bitcoins price is ' + str(current_price) + "!"

        if current_price > target_price:
            body = "Bitcoin is higher than your target price at " + str(current_price) + "."
        elif target_price <= current_price <= target_price_2:
            body = "Bitcoin is in your target price range at " + str(current_price) + "!"
        elif current_price < target_price:
            body = "Bitcoin is below your target price range at " + str(current_price) + "!"

        msg = f'Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}'

        smtp.sendmail(email_user, phone_number, msg)

def check_price(current_price):

    run_loop = True
    print("Enter 'q' to exit the loop")

    while run_loop:

        response = requests.get("https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/spot")
        data = response.json()

        currency = data["data"]["base"]
        current_price = data["data"]["amount"]
        current_price = int(float(current_price))  # converts string float to int

        if current_price:
            send_email(current_price)

        print(f'Bitcoins current price is {current_price}')

        stop_loop = input()
        if stop_loop == 'q':
            run_loop = False
        
        time.sleep(10)


check_price(current_price) #Make call to current_price which ATM is 0
```

Comment: What is the problem with the `while` loop you have now?

Comment: Well the code works when I manually start it. My problem is it doesn't RE-RUN. Say if I wanted an alert every 5 minutes or 30 minutes, or for testing purposes every 20 seconds. I want it to do this without manually rerunning it.

Comment: You can use the code I posted in `app.py` and just run it in your shell. It will continuously loop based on the defined time.

Comment: I do thank you for your answer, but I'm still a beginner programmer and as of right now I don't understand how a docker file works. I would like to find how to make this code work in a way that I'm currently able to understand. That way in the future I will be able to make changes and adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest running it in a docker container. That way you can easily have the script run in the background. You can also use [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/) + Celery beat to have it scheduled.

Here's slightly modified code to run it in a container:

### app.py

```py
import smtplib
import os
import requests
import json
import time

email_user = os.environ.get("EMAIL_USER")  # set your own environment variables
email_password = os.environ.get("APP_PASS")
phone_number = os.environ.get("USER_PHONE")

target_low = 20000  # set your target prices in USD
target_high = 30000

current_price = 0  # declare current price


def send_email(current_price):

    with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587) as smtp:
        smtp.ehlo()
        smtp.starttls()
        smtp.ehlo()

        smtp.login(email_user, email_password)

        subject = "Bitcoin Alert: "
        body = "Bitcoins price is " + str(current_price) + "!"

        if current_price > target_low:
            body = (
                "Bitcoin is higher than your target price at "
                + str(current_price)
                + "."
            )
        elif target_low <= current_price <= target_high:
            body = (
                "Bitcoin is in your target price range at " + str(current_price) + "!"
            )
        elif current_price < target_low:
            body = (
                "Bitcoin is below your target price range at "
                + str(current_price)
                + "!"
            )

        msg = f"Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}"

        smtp.sendmail(email_user, email_user, msg)


def main():
    while True:

        response = requests.get("https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/spot")
        data = response.json()

        currency = data["data"]["base"]
        current_price = data["data"]["amount"]
        current_price = int(float(current_price))  # converts string float to int

        if current_price:
            send_email(current_price)

        print(f"Bitcoins current price is {current_price}")
        time.sleep(30)  # set to desired email interval


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### Dockerfile (generated by VS Code)

```
# For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Install pip requirements
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

# Switching to a non-root user, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-user-rights
RUN useradd appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Run the container continuously in the background on your local machine:

```shell
$ docker run \
> -e EMAIL_USER=$EMAIL_USER \
> -e APP_PASS=$APP_PASS \
> -e USER_PHONE=$USER_PHONE \
> so-test
```

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/schedule/ make a scheduler for your project

Comment: I'll have to look up what this is, but thank you. If possible is there a way for now to just run it off of pure python code?

Comment: Schedule is very interesting, I'm trying now to implement it based on the documentation, but I'm still not getting the alerts at my timed interval. Is there any good examples of how to use this?

Comment: Running something in a Docker container isn't necessary for having the script run continuously.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I understand that it is not necessary but it sure makes it simple.